# How to make a transparent textbox in html

Tags: html, web

I am a new programmer basically a beginner, I am trying out whatever my uncle told me about HTML. I'm trying to find out how to make the first text boxes transparent.

Please help me,
[enter link description here](http://file:///Users/shabarishshanmugam/Downloads/2088_big_city/index.html)

Comment: You have pasted a link to your local machine. We can't access that.

Comment: oh ok sorry. how do i send in files? im new sorry for the troubles

Comment: You can copy paste the contents of the file into here by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67057729/edit).

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "transparent". but maybe something like

```
<form>
<input type="text" style="opacity: 0.5;" />
</form>
```

Anothere thing you might want is to "not display" the textbox, or make it inactive. I recommend you check out https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp

Comment: I want the background to be transparent, the text should be visible thats all

Comment: just increase the opacity .

Comment: Is your background a picture? a PNG picture (background is transparnt by default)? Is your entire background with the page a picture? It's all possible with HTML, it's just a matter of what you want to get done. This could be done with a good HTML programmer, or possibly with a good photoshop user.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to the code:https://www.twitlonger.com/show/n_1srlifs?new_post=true
()9